# HTML hexagon with inner text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a hexagon widget. That should look something like this:

[image]

(Please ignore the lines)

And on mobile something like this:

[image]

Now the hexagon it self should be fairly easy there is a lot of documentation online on how to create them. However there is very little info on how to add text like this.

Usually the hexagon are made of a couple of elements twisted and turned to create the shape.

This isnt very good for my needs because the text would then not be rendered (or be under another div).

using the following CSS:

```
    .hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 115.47px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 57.74px 0;
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  border-right: solid 2px #000000;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 141.42px;
  height: 141.42px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 27.2893px;
}

.hexagon:before {
  top: -70.7107px;
  border-top: solid 2.8284px #000000;
  border-right: solid 2.8284px #000000;
}

.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -70.7107px;
  border-bottom: solid 2.8284px #000000;
  border-left: solid 2.8284px #000000;
}
```

I have created the basic hexagon:

[image]

Here is a fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/c5dk9Lay/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/c5dk9Lay/)

Does any of you have any experience in creating such a widget or know of a work around so that the text can be shown

Comment: Check out this codepen https://codepen.io/darsain/pen/Cxawq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this fiddle. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2uvw73z/)

**HTML:**
    `<div class="hexagon">
    <div class="text">
    <h1>89%</h1>
    <p>My Overall Score</p>
    </div>
    </div>`

**Add CSS:**

```
.text{
  position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: Hey thank you this works do you have any idea of how i might achieve the mobile version?

Comment: Check this fiddle for update. https://jsfiddle.net/n2uvw73z/1/. Just use the media query css for mobile version. Resize result window below 500px to see effect

Comment: Hi, the widths and heights are pretty tight calculated, used some kind of tool to automatically do this?

Comment: i would like to know how i would display the text whenever the user hover over the hexagon.